# How to get the values from duplicate column if the same corresponding row values are empty

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to map the empty value of ticket column with corresponding Order number whose having value to ticket number. But i am not able to get the expected output. 
Can any one please anyone help me in this

My Dataframe:

```
Order number    Ticket 
13902   S0-015581
13902   
13501   
13501   S0-0012131
13809   S0-90-788
13809   S0-90-788
```

Expected Dataframe:

```
Order number    Ticket 
13902   S0-015581
13902   S0-015581
13501   S0-0012131
13501   S0-0012131
13809   S0-90-788
13809   S0-90-788
```

My code:

```
df["Ticket"].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Comment: `df['Ticket'] = df.groupby('Order number').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())`

Comment: @Erfan. I am not getting the result as expected. can you please check expected output above. In your solution just replacing the ticket colum with Order number.

Comment: Can you add your data as text so I can use it, pictures are not the way to provide your data. If you have your data in pandas dataframes, use `print(df)` and copy that output in your question.

Comment: @Erfan, I have updated the post by adding data as text instead of picture. please check once

Comment: The missing values, are they actual empty strings like you've shown, or `NaN`?

Comment: @Erfan, those are NaN values in pandas dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) if instead missing values are mepty strings and then use custom lambda function with forward and back filling missing values:

```
df['Ticket'] = df['Ticket'].replace('', np.nan)

df['Ticket'] = df.groupby('Order number')['Ticket'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
print (df)
   Order number      Ticket
0         13902   S0-015581
1         13902   S0-015581
2         13501  S0-0012131
3         13501  S0-0012131
4         13809   S0-90-788
5         13809   S0-90-788
```

Comment: @Erfan - Sorry, I was in dinner, so now checked old questions...

Comment: @Erfan - but your answer if not specified column working incorrect, because replaced by first column `Order number`